# How do I set state to toggle a boolean value that sits inside an array of JSON object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, state

I've been stuck on this today, and I've tried several possible solutions that didn't resolve the issue.

This is a flip-card effect I'm creating for a team's profile page. When user click on the profile-card it flips the card to show more info on the back. The way I've set up currently flips all the cards all at once when onClick is triggered, instead of the individual card. I know by doing that I need to set the current state of isTrue to render the boolean value from the JSON object, and I tried several possible ways I could think of with no succession.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me learn/understand how to solve this issue!

Here is the simplified example code:

JSON object:

```
data: [
  { id: 1, isTrue: false },
  { id: 2, isTrue: false },
  { id: 3, isTrue: false},   
  ...
]
```

React Component:

```
import exampleData from 'data.js'
class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
       isTrue: //I need to set the current state of isTrue to render from exampleData, but couldn't figure out how to do it.//
    }
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
  }
  handleToggle (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isTrue: !prevState.isTrue
    }))
  }
render() {
  return(
        <div className="App">
         {exampleData.data.map((obj) => {
           return <ReactCardFlip isTrue={this.state.isTrue}/>
             <button onClick={handleToggle}>Flip the card</div>
           </ReactCardFlip>
          })
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You are mapping single state to all the objects in the exampleData. Your state cannot be a single True/False. It has to have a True/False for each object and flip the state for that object for which the onClick is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store `externalData` in your component's state. Render this list using `map` and pass current clicked card to the `toggle` method. After this, you are able to change your state depending on the element you have clicked. See example below:

```
import exampleData from 'data.js'

class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
       cards: [],
    }
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.setState({ cards: exampleData });
  }

  handleToggle (card) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      cards: prevState.cards.map(prevCard => {
        if (prevCard.id === card.id) {
          return {
            id: prevCard.id,
            isTrue: !prevCard.isTrue
          }
       }

       return prevCard;
    })}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       {this.state.data.map((card) => {
         return (
           <ReactCardFlip isTrue={card.isTrue}>
             <button onClick={() => this.handleToggle(card)}>Flip the card</button>
           </ReactCardFlip>
         )
       })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for answering my question. This was very helpful, and lead me to solve the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The main is each item should have its own `isTure`

So the single state `isTrue` cannot achieve your demand.

Two ways:

- `exampleData` in `state`
- `isTure` => `arrIsTrue` to correspond each item in `exampleData`

---

```
data: [
  { id: 1, isTrue: false },
  { id: 2, isTrue: false },
  { id: 3, isTrue: false},   
  ...
]
```

these data can place in `state`

like after: `this.state = { exampleData: exampleData.data }`

so the `render` can be `<ReactCardFlip isTrue={obj.isTrue}/>`

also the `handleToggle` should get current toggle index to after:

```
<div className="App">
  {this.state.exampleData.map((obj, index) => {
    return <ReactCardFlip key={index} isTrue={this.state.isTrue}/>
      <button onClick={() => handleToggle(index)}>Flip the card</div>
    </ReactCardFlip>
  })
</div>
```

and then in `handleToggle` to be:

```
handleToggle (index) {
  const exampleData = this.state.exampleData
  exampleData[index] = !exampleData[index].isTrue
  this.setState({ exampleData: exampleData })
}
```

After all, don't forget `key`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. This explanation partially solved the problem for me and made me noticed I was calling the function incorrectly in another component. I have since resolved the issue. Cheers!